# PHP/SQL list order not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

**A little bit of information**

I am currently working on a project where I can display my work as projects.

In my database I have set it up so the number within `list` tells the PHP where it should be - according to the MYSQL Query.

In my project page I have created pagination so that if there are more than 5 rows, a new project list page is added to the pagination.

(My forward and back pagination is done by images linked)

I use Jquery Ajax POST to call new pages in.

**The problem:**

I used to set my PHP query to order by `name` (project name) but I created a new column `list` so that I could present them in a custom order - according to the digit that is in `list`

But ever since I changed it from `name` to `list` - the page only shows 5 records and no longer gives me my pagination options (when it should)

I know the problem is to do with the 2 queries within the pagination - could anyone tell me how to resolve this.

I have tried making the `list` column Char, Varchar and INT all have not helped! :(

**The Code:**

**PHP Pagination:**

```
    <?
$get_stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `cat`='$arrc' ORDER BY `list` ASC")or die(mysql_error());
$getid = mysql_num_rows($get_stuff);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($get_stuff);
$numrows = $r[0];
// number of rows to show per page
$rowsperpage = 5;
// find out total pages
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

// get the current page or set a default
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && is_numeric($_POST['pid'])) {
   // cast var as int
   $currentpage = (int) $_POST['pid'];
} else {
   // default page num
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// if current page is greater than total pages...
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   // set current page to first page
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

// the offset of the list, based on current page 
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
// get the info from the db 
$get_stuff2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `cat`='$arrc' ORDER BY `list` ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage")or die(mysql_error());
while($projectz = mysql_fetch_array($get_stuff2)){
?>
<ul class="projex">
<li onClick="project('project','<? echo $projectz['id']; ?>','1','<? echo $currentpage; ?>')" class="onclick"> <? echo $projectz['name']; ?>
</ul>
<?
}
?>
```

I have not added my links code in as I know that is not the problem.

Comment: what does the following line: `$numrows = $r[0];` ? I guess it returns an ID which can be less than 5 (the number of items on page in this case) and based on that `ceil` returns 1

Comment: I presume so, it is displaying 5 but there are 7 rows (or records) I should be able to see. But the pagination links are not showing - only when I change the order from a `name` order to `list` number (In other words `text` to `number`) - therefore it is acting like a MAX/LIMIT or otherwise only displaying 5 records.

Comment: I think there is something strange about `$numrows = $r[0];` too.  I think it should be `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($get_stuff);`

Comment: I still don't understand the meaning of this two lines: `$getid = mysql_num_rows($get_stuff); $numrows = $r[0];`, I mean the names of variables are confusing or you wanted to assign them in the other way around? like this: `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($get_stuff); $getid = $r[0];`

Comment: $numrows = mysql_num_rows($get_stuff);

"Fatal error: Unsupported operand types"

Also this is old code that I have reused (I found this pagination the easiest) so not all variables have been renamed for only I until now have had to put up with them, I am not asking for you to complain about the name just help me.

THE PROBLEM (listening) is that only after I changed the MYSQL `order by` (from `name` where it showed the pagination links = 2 pages (or 7 records)) to (`list` where it now shows 5 records and no pagination links) therefore it must be a problem with the order by but I don't see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be here:

```php
<?
$get_stuff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `cat`='$arrc' ORDER BY `list` ASC")or die(mysql_error());
$getid = mysql_num_rows($get_stuff);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($get_stuff);
$numrows = $r[0];
```

You put the number of rows into `$getid`, then ignore that variable and put the first returned column from the results set into `$numrows` and use that. This means all the pagination calculations are based on the first column returned rather than the number of rows. I would guess that when ordered by `name` the first column was 7 and when ordered by `list` the first column is 5 or less.

My suggested fix would be to get the `COUNT` of rows in the SQL query, unless there is a pressing need for `$getid` that is not shown in your example:

```
<?php
$get_stuff = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `projects` WHERE `cat`='$arrc'")or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_row($get_stuff);
$numrows = $r[0];
```